# jQuery Validation - error message does not disappear until submit is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 radio buttons (#r1 and #r2) and a single file input (#file) in my form.

One of the 2 radio buttons must be selected, and the #file has a rule that it is required only when the #r1 is selected.

What I want to do is to make the error message(*) of the #file is disappeared right away when the #r2 is selected.
(** error message: no file is uploaded, which means, the #r1 is selected, but the #file has no file.)

But currently, the error is disappeared only when the submit button is clicked in my code.
How can I fix this?

```
Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/3h92un7j/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you do this:

```
$('#r1').click(function () {
  $('#file').show();
  window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('#file').click();
  },500);
});

$('#r2').click(function () {
  $('#file').hide();
  $("#file-error").hide();
});
```

updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3h92un7j/1/

code change after your edit:
https://jsfiddle.net/3h92un7j/2/

Comment: Thank you so much! It works exactly as I expected it to!

Comment: Nice.
Can you please accept answer if it helped U?
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on("blur", '.error', function () {
  $(this).closest("form").validate()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose `onChange event`

```
$( "input[name=radio]:radio" ).on("change",function(e){
console.log("My value is :",event.target.value=="r2");
if(event.target.value=="r2"){
//do what you need to do.
}
})
```